# Events firing on parents of elements with contenteditable attribute

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, addeventlistener

If an element with the contenteditable attribute is the child of another element with the content editable attribute it appears that any events fired are on the parent rather than the child. How can this behaviour be prevented?

```
<a href="#" contenteditable><img src="logo.png" contenteditable></a>

<script>
var editable = document.querySelectorAll("[contenteditable]");
for(var i=0;i<editable.length;i++){
editable[i].addEventListener("focus",editableFocus,false);
}
function editableFocus(e){
console.log(e.target.nodeName);
}
</script>
```

Comment: take a look at this http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: That was my first thought, but it makes no difference. It appears to be specific to the contenteditable attribute as the problem can be avoided by wrapping the child inside an element with contenteditable set to false. However, I would prefer not to resort to this.